# Mass update the tables in has-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a `One to Many relationship` between Channel and Video table. Both tables have `visibility` field. When I update the visibility of a channel, I want to update the visibility of all the videos that belong to that channel with the visibility value of the channel.

How to achieve this mass update functionality in Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 7):

You could listen for an 'updated' event on that model. Check if that 'visibility' field has changed, if so, then run a query to update all the related records at once.

```
$channel->videos()->update(['visibility' => true]);
```

One possibility. This won't fire any events for those `Video` models as its not actually retrieving them, its just firing an update directly on the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it worked like a charm

```
$channel->videos()->update([
    'visibility' => $channel->visibility,
]);
```